# In a dataframe, find the index of the next smaller value for each element of a column

Tags: r, dplyr

**Question:**

In a dataframe, I want to create a new column as the indices of the next smaller value of an existing column.

For example, the data looks like this. It is already arranged in `item, day`.

```
  item day val 
1    1   2   3 
2    1   4   2 
3    1   5   1 
4    2   1   1 
5    2   3   2 
6    2   5   3
```

First I would like to use `group_by(item)` in `dplyr` to select the sub-dataframe of each item.

Then for row 1, I **look down** the rows and find that row 2 has a smaller `val`. This is what I want, so I record the `day` corresponding to that row. Similar for row 2.

Note that for row 3 and 6, they are the last rows of corresponding sub-dataframes, so there is no next smaller value. For row 4 and 5, there is no smaller `val` when I **look down** the rows.

The dataframe with the new column should look like this.

```
  item day val next.smaller.day
1    1   2   3                4
2    1   4   2                5
3    1   5   1               -1
4    2   1   1               -1
5    2   3   2               -1
6    2   5   3               -1
```

I wonder if there is any way of using `dplyr` to implement this, or any codes in `r` other than a for loop.

I found a thread asking the algorithm of this question. [Given an array, find out the next smaller element for each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493853/given-an-array-find-out-the-next-smaller-element-for-each-element) .
It is relevant, and the proposed algorithm beats mine in terms of time complexity, but I still find it hard to implement in my scenario.

Thank you!

*Update:*

Here is another example to re-illustrate what I'm looking for.

```
  item day val next.smaller.day
1    1   2   2                5
2    1   4   3                5
3    1   5   1               -1
4    2   1   3                3
5    2   3   1               -1
6    2   5   2               -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group your data by the item, calculate the different between rows using the `diff` function and check if it is smaller than zero which will then generate a logic vector and you can use the logic vector to pick up the next day. And since you are picking up the next day, you will need the `lead` function to shift the day column forward so that it can match the rows where you want to place them.

*Side note*: Since `diff` function create a vector one element shorter than the original one and you will always leave the last row out per group, we can pad the `diff` result by a `FALSE` condition.

```
library(dplyr);
df %>% group_by(item) %>% mutate(smaller = c(diff(val) < 0, F), 
                                 next.smaller.day = ifelse(smaller, lead(day), -1)) %>%
       select(-smaller)

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: item [2]

#    item   day   val next.smaller.day
#   <int> <int> <int>            <dbl>
# 1     1     2     3                4
# 2     1     4     2                5
# 3     1     5     1               -1
# 4     2     1     1               -1
# 5     2     3     2               -1
# 6     2     5     3               -1
```

*Update*:

```
find.next.smaller <- function(ini = 1, vec) {
    if(length(vec) == 1) NA 
    else c(ini + min(which(vec[1] > vec[-1])), 
          find.next.smaller(ini + 1, vec[-1]))
}       # the recursive function will go element by element through the vector and find out 
        # the index of the next smaller value.

df %>% group_by(item) %>% mutate(next.smaller.day = day[find.next.smaller(1, val)], 
                                 next.smaller.day = replace(next.smaller.day, is.na(next.smaller.day), -1)) 

# Source: local data frame [6 x 4]
# Groups: item [2]
#
#    item   day   val next.smaller.day
#   <int> <int> <dbl>            <dbl>
# 1     1     2     2                5
# 2     1     4     3                5
# 3     1     5     1               -1
# 4     2     1     1               -1
# 5     2     3     2               -1
# 6     2     5     3               -1
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What you did works in the given example. However, it is possible that the next smaller value is not in the next row. For example, if `val` is `2,3,1` and `day` is `2,4,5`, I expect the output to be `5,5,-1`. Do you have any idea how to implement this?

Comment: See the update. You can write a recursive function to find the index of the next smaller value, then apply it using the `dplyr` function.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to write a function to achieve my goal, but I couldn't figure it out. Your solution works very well. Let me learn the spirit of the recursive nature of your function and try to apply it next time. Many thanks again!