# Filter a dataframe to keep only rows that are increasingly smaller than the first row

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, apply, purrr

I have a dataframe, which is sorted in descending order by the `abc` column (and needs to remain that way). So, beginning with the first row (i.e., where `ID` is 1259 and `value` is 4054), I want to keep the next row that has a lower value in the `value` column, which would be row 2 (i.e., `value` is 3902). Then, based on that value in row 2 (3902), I would then want to select the next lowest value row (i.e., `3801` in row 4). Then, based on that value in row 4 (3801), I would select the next lowest value row (i.e., rows 5-7 with a `value` of 1314), and so on. I also want to retain rows that are selected that have duplicate values (e.g., `1314` value for rows 5-7).

**Data**

```
# A tibble: 42 × 3
      ID   abc value
   <int> <dbl> <dbl>
 1  1259  4530 4054.
 2  1617  4415 3902.
 3  2441  4250 5286.
 4   539  4161 3801.
 5  1471  4012 1314.
 6   687  3934 1314.
 7  2436  3900 1314.
 8  1295  3591 3558.
 9  1738  3493 1188.
10  1747  3366 3902.
# … with 32 more rows

df <- structure(list(ID = c(1259L, 1617L, 2441L, 539L, 1471L, 687L, 
2436L, 1295L, 1738L, 1747L, 672L, 2187L, 2214L, 738L, 1784L, 
726L, 1712L, 2961L, 137L, 1188L, 1824L, 2856L, 953L, 2579L, 2010L, 
484L, 2769L, 1736L, 2994L, 1572L, 586L, 2462L, 2180L, 1404L, 
1472L, 1007L, 3000L, 545L, 2098L, 2029L, 2557L, 1623L), abc = c(4530, 
4415, 4250, 4161, 4012, 3934, 3900, 3591, 3493, 3366, 3248, 3172, 
3172, 3004, 3004, 2939, 2853, 2782, 2541, 2439, 2371, 2116, 2005, 
1999, 1838, 1749, 1611, 1573, 1416, 1301, 1177, 1074, 975, 805, 
729, 680, 538, 494, 309, 297, 155, 0), value = c(4053.69672793727, 
3902.10003271411, 5286.47420784735, 3801.25160651053, 1314.10007572174, 
1314.10007572174, 1314.10007572174, 3557.56126600696, 1188.20000553131, 
3902.10003271411, 1543.90001773834, 1543.90001773834, 1543.90001773834, 
1228.10004138947, 1228.10004138947, 1618.80007553101, 1618.80007553101, 
2787.70004177094, 2877.32907307533, 1289.59995269775, 2640.10003471375, 
1618.80007553101, 3557.56126600696, 3902.10003271411, 1228.10004138947, 
1329.40004730225, 1228.10004138947, 3557.56126600696, 1618.80007553101, 
1206.79998779297, 2117.7806730578, 1206.79998779297, 1206.79998779297, 
3260.02910244849, 1191.90001773834, 1191.90001773834, 1029.70001125336, 
1336.000041008, 1091.09995365143, 1234.89997673035, 1164.4999704361, 
1191.90001773834)), row.names = c(NA, -42L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**Expected Output**

```
     ID   abc value
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1259  4530 4054.
2  1617  4415 3902.
3   539  4161 3801.
4  1471  4012 1314.
5   687  3934 1314.
6  2436  3900 1314.
7  1738  3493 1188.
8  3000   538 1030.
```

I know I could do something like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38207938/15293191) to find the next lowest value for each row, but I am unsure how to go through and `filter`. Since this can skip several rows, using `lag` and `lead` did not work for me. I would like to be able to do this with `tidyverse` or `data.table` or the `apply` family. I would like to avoid using a for loop, unless that's the only way. I have a larger dataset, so I am looking for an efficient way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, value == cummin(value))


# A tibble: 8 × 3
     ID   abc value
  <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  1259  4530 4054.
2  1617  4415 3902.
3   539  4161 3801.
4  1471  4012 1314.
5   687  3934 1314.
6  2436  3900 1314.
7  1738  3493 1188.
8  3000   538 1030.
```

Comment: Well that's much simpler than I was trying to do it; I think I need to spend more time looking into the cumulative functions!

Comment: Upvoted for its simplicity and elegance, and this works great with this data. For future readers, realize that if the numbers have fine levels of precision (many relevant decimal places), then this may produce inconsistent/incorrect results, and do so without warning or error. This would be related to floating-point comparisons (in any language, not just R); refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9508518/3358272, https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: The more verbose way around this would be to look for a tolerance, something like `filter(df, abs(value - cummin(value)) < 1e-9)`, where the `1e-9` is context-sensitive. Even this might be imperfect if there might be a real value `1e-10` above the `cummin(value)`, meaning it would be incorrectly retained; this is why I say *"context-sensitive"* :-)

Comment: Good point. More verbosely, we could use `df %>% mutate(value_rnd = round(value, 2)) %>% filter(value_rnd == cummin(value_rnd))` where we pick an appropriate precision in the `round` function depending on the context.