# How can I find the occurence number of each suffix in a string?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, hash, suffix-array

I want to find how many times each suffix of a string occurs in the **original** string in O(nlogn) or O(n) time.

For example, for string aba, suffix a appears twice, ba appears once, aba appears once.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have read it :) Where am I wrong?

Comment: You need to ask a specific question about an algorithm or piece of code, not just "how do I do all of it".

Comment: I'm just asking for an algorithm... I mean, how can I input a string, and output the occurence number of each suffix in O(nlogn) in total. Isn't it specific? I'm not going to focus on the detail of the code, just need an algorithm.

Comment: @newbie How suffix `a` appears twice? I think total suffix here is 3: `a. ba. aba`

Comment: I mean suffix a appears twice in the original string 'aba'. I want to count occurences like this.

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array for a start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Suffix Array Solution**

Construct suffix tree of the string S along with LCP array. This will help in counting all the occurrences of each suffix.

without learning what suffix array and LCP are, its difficult to understand.

[suffix array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)

[LCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LCP_array)

[kasai’s Algorithm for Construction of LCP array from Suffix Array](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/%C2%AD%C2%ADkasais-algorithm-for-construction-of-lcp-array-from-suffix-array/)

Let us take an example string and create its suffix array. Consider the string S = "ABABBAABB".

```
suffix positions(pos)   Suffixes of S   LCP array of S
    5                   AABB            1
    0                   ABABBAABB       2
    6                   ABB             3
    2                   ABBAABB         0
    8                   B               1
    4                   BAABB           2
    1                   BABBAABB        1
    3                   BBAABB          2
    7                   BB              not Defined
```

First column(**pos array**) is the original starting points of sorted suffixes in Suffix Array. Let call second column as **SuffixArray** (we do not need to compute it, its just for visualization).

Now, as we know LCP[i]= the length of longest common prefix between SuffixArray[i] and SuffixArray[i+1]. e.g. LCP[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_array)=lcp("ABABBAABB","ABB")=2.

Let Count[i] = number of occurrences of suffix starting at position i.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; )
{
    int j=i;
    while(LCP[j]==n-pos[j]){ // loop if SuffixArray[j] is a prefix of SuffixArray[j+1] 
        j++;
    }
    int incr=1;
    for (int k = j-1; k>= i ; --k)
    {
        count[ pos[k] ] = incr;
        incr++;
    } 
    i=j+1;
}
```

This is highly optimized solution and if you look closely towards all steps, Complexity is **O(n log n)**.

Hope it helps. Please go through everything again if you do not understand in the first try.

---

**EDIT:** **There is tiny bug in this computation of count array.** Basically my problem is to find the immediate next index in the LCP array which is smaller than current value. I am providing the correct implementation .

```
stack< int > stack;

count[ pos[n-1] ] = 1;

for(int i=n-2;i>=0;i--){
    while(!stack.empty() and LCP[stack.top()]>=LCS[i]){
        stack.pop();
    }

    if( LCP[i] == n-pos[i]  ){
        if (stack.empty())
        {
            count[ pos[i] ] = n-i ;
        }else{
            count[ pos[i] ] = stack.top()-i ;
        }

    }else{
        count[ pos[i] ] = 1;
    }

    stack.push(i);

}
```

[next smaller element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493853/given-an-array-find-out-the-next-smaller-element-for-each-element)

---

Comment: Is k supposed to be i in your edit? is count a single dimension array of size n?