# Time Complexity dealing with List of size 10**6

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, time-complexity

I recently failed a coding challenge which deals with time complexity. I've been tinkering with it in my spare time but still can't get it to work quickly for large lists. I had initially over-thought the problem, refactored it, etc., made some incremental improvements, tried using `pandas` (which turned out to be *much* slower), etc.

I am interested in learning what methods I might use to improve the execution speed of this code.

> **Input:** a list with maximum size `10**6` containing unsorted integers in `range(1,10**5)`.
>
> The task is to compute the "total price" from this arbitrary construct and return the "total price" *and* an ordered list of *indices* representing those items that were *not* discounted.
>
> An item at index `i` has its price discounted by the *next smaller/lower item*. If there are no smaller values in `items[i+1:]`, the item's price is not discounted (or you can consider it discounted by `0`).
>
> **Example Input:** `items = [5, 3, 4, 1, 5]`
>
> **Example Output:** `13, [3, 4]`
>
> Here, `items[0]` is discounted by `items[1]`, `items[1]` is discounted by `items[3]`, `items[2]` is discounted by `items[3]`, `items[3]` and `items[4]` are not discounted.
>
> So the total price is `13`, given by `(5-3) + (3-1) + (4-1) + (1-0) + (5-0)`

I have a function that solves this pretty quickly for most cases, but as we start to approach the maximum size of the list, it's taking much longer.  For example, a list of length 50000 is processed in < 1 second. A list of length 100K is processed in <3 seconds. A list of length 200K takes <10 seconds, and 400K takes about 50 seconds. **Running against a million items takes ~1000+ seconds.**

For testing, I create a large list like so and then I pass it (or slices of it) to the functions, like:

```
data = list(np.array(np.random.randint(1,10**5,(10**6)), dtype='int64'))
total, full_price = get_total(data[:100000])
```

Here is the faster, non-`pandas` function:

```
def get_total(data):
    init_total = sum(data)
    items = data[:] 
    size = len(items)
    discount = [get_discount(items.pop(0),items) for i in range(size)]
    full = [i for (i,v) in enumerate(discount) if v == 0]
    total = init_total - sum(discount)
    return total, full, None

def get_discount(this, _items):
    next_lowest_index, discount = next(((x,val) for x, val in enumerate(_items) if val < this), (np.NaN, 0))
    return discount
```

I mentioned I had tried `pandas` as well, but this code is *much* slower even on small lists (n=1000). I tried sorting it by value:

```
def frame_total(data):
    if type(data) == list:
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = data[:].sort_values(0, 'index')
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'val':data[0],
                        'discount': [0] * data.shape[0]
                        }, dtype='int')
    df.discount = [next(iter(df.loc[(df.index > i) & (df.val < row.val)].sort_index().val),0) 
                   for i,row in df.iterrows()]
    total = data.sum() - df.discount.sum()
    full_indices = list(df[df.discount == 0].sort_index().index)
    return total, full_indices, None
```

And another that does not sort the input data which is not perceptibly faster:

```
def frame2(data):
    if type(data) == list:
        data = pd.DataFrame(data)
    data = data[:]
    df = pd.DataFrame({ 'val':data[0],
                        'discount': [0] * data.shape[0]
                        }, dtype='int')
    df.discount = [next(iter(df.val[i+1:].loc[df.val < row.val]),0) for i,row in df.iterrows()]
    total = data.sum() - df.discount.sum()
    full_indices = list(df[df.discount == 0].index)
    return total, full_indices, None
```

Note that the full-price items are more likely to exist towards the end of the list (as `i` increases, probability that any value < `items[i]` exists in `items[i+1:]` decreases). I feel like this is important, but I can't grok how to make use of that.

## Solved, thanks @DarrylG and to [the explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493853/given-an-array-find-out-the-next-smaller-element-for-each-element)

```
def get_next_smallest(data,default=0):
    """
        returns the discounted value for all items in a list
        discounted value is the next smaller item in the list, e.g.:
        for any n, the next smallest item is the first item in data[n+1:] < data[n]
        provides O(n) complexity solution.
    """
    discounts=[default for i in data] # stores the corresponding next smaller value
    stack = [] # initialize our empty stack
    for i, this in enumerate(data):
        while len(stack) > 0 and this < data[stack[-1]]:
            discounts[stack.pop()] = this
        stack.append(i)
    return discounts

def get_total(data):
    init_total = sum(data)
    default = 0  # should be a value that will NOT be present in the data, like 0 or -1
    discounts = get_next_smallest(data, default)
    full = [i for i,v in enumerate(discounts) if v == default]
    total = init_total - sum(discounts)
    return total, full
```

Comment: This question would fit better on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @mkrieger. Technically, the code does not perform according to requirements, so it's suitable for SO. OP has done enough research that this is not a question of aesthetics. Also, this looks like a fun problem :)

Comment: You need to figure out an algorithm that doesn't require searching the entire rest of the list for each element, because that's `O(n**2)`. Consider the worst case example `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, ..., 1]`. I suspect it involves finding local maxima and minima.

Comment: @Barmar my understanding is that the `next` generator in the `get_discount` function should avoid that pitfall.  I test that method on a list [2,2,2...,1] with size 10**6 and the return value is *immediately* given in console.

Comment: There's an algorithm that finds the "next smaller element" of each element in an array in O(n) (example of implementation is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493853/given-an-array-find-out-the-next-smaller-element-for-each-element).  Seems this could be easily used to find total_cost in O(n).

Comment: Just taking a quick look at your code, `items.pop(0)` is pretty expensive if it's performed many times.

Comment: A hint: you can also calculate it as `5 - (1 * 3) + 3 + 4 - (2 * 1) + 1 + 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By iterating on your data backwards, as suggested by @Mad Physicist, you can get an algorithm needing much less memory, and also being faster:

```
def get_total(data):
    tot = sum(data)
    smallest_tail = deque()
    no_discount = []
    i = len(data) - 1 # manually handle the index
    for x in reversed(data):
        while smallest_tail:
            s = smallest_tail[-1]
            if s >= x: # s won't be next smaller for anyone because of x
                smallest_tail.pop()
            else:
                tot -= s
                break
        if not smallest_tail:
            no_discount.append(i)
        smallest_tail.append(x)
        i -= 1
    return tot, list(reversed(no_discount))
```

comparing with your current solution (on my machine):

```
:data = list(np.array(np.random.randint(1, 10**5, 10**6, dtype='int64')))
:get_total_dz(data) == get_total(data)
True
:%timeit r = get_total_dz(data) # yours, replacing 'len(stack) > 0' with 'stack'
672 ms ± 6.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
:%timeit r = get_total(data) # mine
435 ms ± 2.29 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you chose to use `deque` instead of `list`?

Comment: I used `deque` instead of `list` because it's slightly faster (and once again @Mad Physicist advertised it), try it at home ;) With `list` I get around 480ms on my machine. For some explenations, you can look e.g. at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23487307/python-deque-vs-list-performance-comparison

Answer (score 2):

Here's an algorithm that's O(n)--using algorithm from [Given an array, find out the next smaller element for each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9493853/given-an-array-find-out-the-next-smaller-element-for-each-element) to find next smaller element

```
def find_next_smaller_elements(xs):
 " finds next smallest element in O(n) "
    ys=[-1 for x in xs]
    stack=[]
    for i,x in enumerate(xs):
        while len(stack)>0 and x<xs[stack[-1]]:
           ys[stack.pop()]=x
        stack.append(i)
    return ys

def get_total(data):
" Computes desired cost function "
    next_smaller = find_next_smaller_elements(data)

    return sum([ x[0] if x[1] == -1 else x[0]-x[1]  for x in list(zip(data, next_smaller))])
```

Test (small list)

```
data = [5, 3, 4, 1, 5]
print(get_total(data)) # 13
```

Timing Test

```
for k in [1000, 10000, 100000, 1000000]:
    data = list(np.array(np.random.randint(1,10**5,k, dtype='int64')))
    t0 = time.time()
    ans = get_total(data)
    print(k, time.time()-t0)
```

Results:

- No.Items =>    Time (seconds)
- 1000     =>    0.0029
- 10000    =>    0.0369
- 100000   =>    0.2059
- 1000000  =>    1.96400

Thus a million items in only 2 seconds.

Comment: This is great. will test it out late this evening. Cheers

Comment: wow. i'm getting a million items in 0.16 seconds. unbelievable.

Comment: @DavidZemens--wow, that's amazing going from ~1000+ seconds to 0.16 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hint: you can compute the ordered indices in a single pass. The trick is to step along the list backwards:

```
def find_undiscounted(data):
    skipped = [len(data) - 1]
    current = data[-1]
    for i in range(len(data) - 2, -1, -1):
        if current >= data[i]:
            skipped.append(i)
            current = data[i]
    return skipped[::-1]
```

A comprehensive solution will require a stack, but can clearly be done in a single pass. Don't forget to use `collections.deque` if you decide to implement it that way.